# Не работает переключатель для radio

Tags: jquery, radio

Приветствую, товарищи!
Есть вот такая разметка:

```
<ul class="form__list form__list">
                    <li class="form__checkbox-wrapp">
                        <input type="radio" name="capital" id="capital1">
                        <label for="capital1">up to $25 000</label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="form__checkbox-wrapp">
                        <input type="radio" name="capital" id="capital2" checked>
                        <label for="capital2">up to $100 000</label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="form__checkbox-wrapp">
                        <input type="radio" name="capital" id="capital3">
                        <label for="capital3">up to $500 000</label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="form__checkbox-wrapp">
                        <input type="radio" name="capital" id="capital4">
                        <label for="capital4">over $1 000 000</label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="form__checkbox-wrapp">
                        <input type="radio" name="capital" id="capital5" class="js-checked-capital">
                        <label for="capital5">Другое</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="form__input-wrapp form__input-wrapp--hidden js-show-capital">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="">
                </div>
```

И вот такой JS:

```
var inpCheckbox = $('.js-checked-key'),
    showInpOne = $('.js-show-key'),
    inpRadio = $('.js-checked-capital'),
    showInpTwo = $('.js-show-capital');

function checkedInput(check, visible) {

    check.click(function () {
        if (check.is(':checked')) {
            visible.addClass('js-inp-visible');
        } else{
            visible.removeClass('js-inp-visible');
        }
    })

}

checkedInput(inpCheckbox, showInpOne);

checkedInput(inpRadio, showInpTwo);
```

Так вот, для чекбоксов этот код отрабатывает и скрытый инпут появляется на экране, а для радиобаттона добавляет класс на скрытый инпут, показывает его, но когда я убираю с состояние чекед с последнего радио, то скрытый инпут все равно остается.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем дело и как это решить?

Comment: "когда я убираю с состояние чекед с последнего радио" - кaк?

Comment: ставлю чекед на другой радиобаттон

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что когда Вы щелкаете по одной из первых четырех радио-кнопок, никакого клика на `.js-checked-capital` не происходит.

Comment: я понял свою ошибку, спасибо за подсказку)